# Do I need to install Thrift on both my servers (Application/DB)?

Tags: php, cloud, cassandra

Here is my situation. I have two servers. One as all my applications (PHP), the second as Cassandra DB with Solr (Solandra), and OpsCenter.

I am using PHP on my application server to access my Cassandra data with PHPCassa.

My question is, do I need to install Thrift on my application and/or my DB server?

**UPDATE**

I have install thrift and cassandra together on one server in the past and it worked. My problem to day is that I have two servers. One with the applications and one with Cassandra. My question is how can I make PHP talk Cassandra on the other server?

Because when I look at my notes, it seems I need to install PHP with Thrift and Cassandra all in one server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the client you need it to have php support. There are a few options.
Look at http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/ThriftExamples#PHP for examples.

Comment: But that assumes that PHP/thrift/cassandra are setup on the same server.

Comment: because it builds the thrift modules - if you just need the driver look at the client options - http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/ClientOptions06